# How to make call using phonegap?

Tags: cordova

I have some contacts read from emulator.I want to know how to make call.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make a href using the tel: protocol:

```
<a href="tel:18005551212">Directory Assistance</a>
```

Then when the user taps on the link the dialer app will be started.